# Is this strictly for software recomendation?

Tags: discussion

For example, I use [OBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Broadcaster_Software) and I had problems. Hardware encoding only works if I don't encode a lot and I wonder why they design it that way.

Is that appropriate?

Answer (score 7):

> Hardware encoding only works if I don't encode a lot and I wonder why they design it that way

I could be wrong, but that doesn't sound like a recommendation question to me.

Choosing the right video encoding given the set of requirements *is* a recommendation question, but it's perhaps better suited on our sister site [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You are correct, and your recommendation is a good one! :)  Also, I think if the OP files an issue report with the OBS developers, good things may happen.

Comment: So this stackexchange is not, for example, for customer support

Comment: @user4951 no. See the [Help Center](/help/on-topic); every site in the network has one.